# Bind uib-tab heading to a scope property

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-tabset

I'm using uib-tabset

```
<uib-tabset class="tab-animation" id="tabSet">
                        <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" ng-click="onTabClick($index)"
                                 active="tab.active"
                                 disable="tab.disabled">
                            <div ng-include="tab.content"></div>
                        </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

Controller :

```
 /**
     * The buzz page tabs
     * @type {*[]}
     */
    $scope.tabs = [
        {title: 'Content', content: 'views/view.html'},
        {title: 'Tools', content: 'views/view2.html'},
        {title: 'Fans', content: 'views/view3.html'}
    ];
```

I want to add a number that can be changed after the initialize of the tubset.
The problem that i can't bind the tabset heading to a '$scope property or inseat it a ng-bind

For example Content(12)

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the Solution.

I just had to use uibTabHeadingTransclude directive of the UI.bootstrap.

Comment: What's the difference ?

Comment: because internally `ui-bootstrap`'s `uibTabContentTransclude` to convert `uib-tab-heading` to `uibTabHeadingTransclude` directive..